# How to autowire cache adapter in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, autowired, symfony-dependency-injection

Using Symfony 7, I have defined my custom cache pool:

```yaml
framework:
    cache:
        default_redis_provider: '%env(resolve:REDIS_URL)%'
        pools:
            cache.score:
                adapter: cache.adapter.redis_tag_aware
```

[According to symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cache.html#creating-custom-namespaced-pools) the proper way to autowire is using `CacheInterface $cacheScore`. While this does autowire the `RedisTagAwareAdapter` in my case, strictly speaking it restricts me to the `CacheInterface` methods (at least in my IDE, but also there is no guarantee that the object I get is going to implement anything else than the `CacheInterface`).

The problem is that this interface implements limited methods, it lacks the `AdapterInterface::getItem()` function. To be clear, every adapter implements both `CacheInterface` (which provides `get` method using cache contracts) and `AdapterInterface` which is based on the native PHP's `Psr\Cache\CacheItemPoolInterface` and provides `getItem`.

In my use-case I need to use both of these at the same time. I did not find which class I should autowire for this to work. I tried `AbstractAdapter` - this fails

> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\RuntimeException :
> Cannot autowire service "App\ScorePredictor\DuelScorePredictor":
> argument "$cacheScore" of method "__construct()" references class
> "Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\AbstractAdapter" but no such service
> exists. Try changing the type-hint to one of its parents: interface
> "Symfony\Contracts\Cache\CacheInterface", or interface
> "Psr\Cache\CacheItemPoolInterface".

The problem as I explained is that each of the interfaces provide only half of the functionality I need.

I cannot even autowire explicitly the `RedisTagAwareAdapter` type, because the same error is thrown.

I need a solution that will provide me with flexibility, so that if I would like to change Redis adapter, I can do so only in `cache.yaml` and no code modification would be needed.

P.S. The `symfony console debug:autowiring cache` does not help either:

```
Autowirable Types
=================

The following classes & interfaces can be used as type-hints when autowiring:
(only showing classes/interfaces matching cache)

CacheItemPoolInterface generates CacheItemInterface objects.
Psr\Cache\CacheItemPoolInterface - alias:cache.app
Psr\Cache\CacheItemPoolInterface $cacheScore - target:cache.score    

Covers most simple to advanced caching needs.
Symfony\Contracts\Cache\CacheInterface - alias:cache.app
Symfony\Contracts\Cache\CacheInterface $cacheScore - target:cache.score

Allows invalidating cached items using tags.
Symfony\Contracts\Cache\TagAwareCacheInterface - alias:cache.app.taggable
Symfony\Contracts\Cache\TagAwareCacheInterface $cacheScore - target:cache.score
```